# Arduino mega + Ethernet shield: Mysql connector to xampp local server

Tags: mysql, arduino, xampp

I have downloaded mysql-connector library from arduino manage-libraries.

It compiles all things right but after I try to send data to xampp-laptop-server it seems not doing any connecting... The serial write only "Connecting..." and then nothing else happen.

It seems like it stop working when trying connection (or going to infinite loop). if(conn.connect(server_addr,3306,user,password)){ } <-- This seems not working.

I tryed open right ports etc. also I have not got any other problems.

Can it be problem that I m forwarding ip right to xampp-localhost? When mostly time it has folders and files in folders) which are using those sql-queries?

Comment: It seems that function Mysql Packet::send_authentication_packet(char *user, char *password) makes this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was mysql-server-permissions. It didnt accept full connection from other local machine. Needed grant all services for root user.